# Sorting elements in array with a certain condition

Tags: php, array, sorting, url

This is what I have:

`function get_create` returns a link with new filtered/sorted properties:

[Code on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcVMs.png)

```
function get_create ($new_query = array(), $script = null, $ext = true, $amp = true) {  
   $pr_url = $GLOBALS['pref_url'].$GLOBALS['host_name'];
   $arr_query = array();

if (!empty($new_query)):

   $new_query = array_filter($new_query, function($element) {
        return !empty($element);}); //delete empty elements

 if ($ext) {
   $cur_url = str_replace("&amp;", "&",$GLOBALS['cur_url'])
   $str_query = parse_url($cur_url, PHP_URL_QUERY); // get string of queries 
   parse_str($str_query,$arr_query); // create an array with queries

   $arr_query = array_replace_recursive($arr_query,$new_query)
   $arr_query = get_sort_by_key($arr_query); 
 }
 else {
   $arr_query = $new_query; // if $new_query empty
 }

 //make a new link with new parameters
  $fn_query = (!empty($arr_query) ? '?'.http_build_query($arr_query,'',($amp ? '&amp;' : '')) : null);
  $fn_script = (!empty($script) ? $script : $GLOBALS['script_name']);

 return $pr_url.$fn_script.$fn_query; // return the link
else : 
 return $GLOBALS['home_url']; 
endif; 

} // end func
```

In parameters we have:

1. `$new_query` (which contains the new properties for `$_get` part)
2. `$script` (contain a new way to script, where data)
3. `$ext` (boolean given parameter which make the logic different)
4. `$amp` (if true then formats and again)

`function get_sort_by_key` helps with sorting array (the keys in array must be in this order: lng-topic-page-sort-search).

[Code 2 on screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PHfG.png)

```
function get_sort_by_key($array = array()) {
$new_array = array();
 foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $key = strtolower(trim($key));
    switch ($key) {
        case $key == 'lng': $order = 0; 
            break;
        case $key == 'topic': $order = 1; 
            break;
        case $key == 'page': $order = 2; 
            break;
        case $key == 'sort': $order = 3; 
            break;
        case $key == 'search': $order = 4; 
            break;
        default: $order = 5; break;     
    }
    $new_array[$order][$key] = $value;
 }

ksort($new_array);
   return $fn_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$new_array);
}
```

I need to create the function which gets an array full of new parameters and adds or replaces the current `$_GET` by them in a specific order.

An example:

I had the URL like this: `http://localhost/test.php`. After initialization func: `get_create(array('sort' => 1, 'topic' => 2)` I get  `http://localhost/test.php?topic=2&sort=1`, where the order is important (not `http://localhost/test.php?sort=1&topic=2`).

How can I make the function look better? My code works, at least now. But I know that I'm wrong. Maybe some elegant solution exists in my case.

Comment: Is that your real code? There appear to be missing semi-colons on the 10th and 14th lines of  the first function...

Comment: If you fix the code so that it works, we'll re-open this question

Comment: Yes this is mine, the colons missing because I tried to make code more readable.

Comment: @Medion Please don't edit your actual code to make it more readable, we are fully capable of reading code :) Is there anything else that you've edited / simplified before posting here?

Comment: Now the code looks like in my project, with some useful changes (thanks to @SamOnela)

Comment: And thank you guys for your activity i'm very appreciate that, i had never seen something like that (as you may see I am a new one on this site).

Comment: That's good to hear, however: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead.

Comment: @Mast OK, I shall know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I make the function look better?*

One alternative approach to the `switch` statement inside `get_sort_by_key()` is to define a lookup-table using an array:

```
define('KEY_MAPPING', ['lng','topic','page','sort','search']);
```

(or it could be a constant defined on a class if such a relevant class exists).

Then the code block in the `foreach` can be simplified using [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) to see if a corresponding index is returned. If not (i.e. it returned `false`) then use 5 as the fallback value.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $key = strtolower(trim($key));
    $order = array_search($key, KEY_MAPPING);
    if ($order === false) {
        $order = 5;
    }
    $new_array[$order][$key] = $value;
 }
```

[See this playground example for a demonstration](https://www.tehplayground.com/LNWx1WmBJtPaVYAK).

For small lists of parameters like this the time difference won't be much. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6852652/1575353) from 6 years ago (and the results may have changed since [Ariel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6888280/1575353) as PHP internals have changed but likely not by much).

I tried to find some online posts comparing `switch` statements with array lookups. The first couple results I see in Google are 6-9 years old:

- [TechnoSophos: Microbenchmarking PHP: Switch Statements are Slow](http://technosophos.com/2011/08/18/microbenchmarking-php-switch-statements-are-slow.html)
- [DevShed: PHP: The Switch Statement and Arrays](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/php/php-the-switch-statement-and-arrays/) ("*can they not indent??*")
- [ExceptionsHub: In PHP what's faster, big Switch statement, or Array key lookup](https://exceptionshub.com/in-php-whats-faster-big-switch-statement-or-array-key-lookup.html)

The general consensus is that the array lookup is faster. And typically it can require fewer lines of code. There is a quote somebody said (I can't remember who, so if you know who to give credit please let me know): "*The easiest line to debug is the line you didn't write*".

Answer (score 2):

1. The default behavior of `array_filter()` is greedy about destroying falsey values.

   ```
   $new_query = array_filter($new_query, function($element) { return !empty($element);});
   ```

   is identical in functionality to:

   ```
   $new_query = array_filter($new_query);
   ```
2. I recommend consistently using curly braces on all constructs and logical tabbing to make your code more readable.
3. When a scalar or array type variable is *sure* to exist and you want to check if it is empty/non-empty or falsey/truthy, then don't use `empty()`.  Just use `if ($variable) {` to check.  (e.g. `$new_query`, `$arr_query`, and `$script`)
4. For `get_sort_by_key()`, a key-based lookup will always outperform a value-based lookup (`in_array()` or `array_search()`). Because php arrays are hash maps, key searches (`array_key_exists()` or `isset()`) are the way to go.  Here is a basic demonstration of how easy and clean it is to execute a custom key sort: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0thJi))

   ```
   $lookup = [
       'lng' => 5,
       'topic' => 4,
       'page' => 3,
       'sort' => 2,
       'search' => 1,
       // do not declare a key with a zero value
   ];

   uksort(
       $input,
       function($a, $b) use($lookup) {
           return ($lookup[$b] ?? 0) <=> ($lookup[$a] ?? 0);
       }
   );
   ```

   The above snippet uses descending values for your known keys.  The zero value is deliberately excluded from the lookup because when the sorting algorithm finds a key which is not represented in the lookup, it is assigned a sorting value of `0` (it goes to the back of the array).  The spaceship operator is a super-versatile tool.  If you wanted to sort by your custom order THEN sort alphabetically in an ascending direction, you can simply declare two balanced arrays like this:

   ```
   return [$lookup[$b] ?? 0, $a] <=> [$lookup[$a] ?? 0, $b];
   ```

As for the maintainability of your code, whenever you want to adjust the priority of specific keys for custom sorting, you only need to touch your lookup array (not the `uksort()` block).  This makes readability and maintenance a breeze.